# namenode goes in safemode every time i re-start machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, safe-mode

I have Hadoop 1.x on ubuntu

Everything works fine: I'm able to upload input file in HDFS. But when I reboot my laptop, all HDFS blocks are corrupted and NameNode starts in SafeMode

So I have to

1) Leave the SafeMode

2) Delete all corrupted blocks with

hdfs fsck -delete

3)Re-upload input file

Then it works fine until next reboot.

Can someone please get me some solution for this. Thanks

Comment: I think your first problem is using Hadoop 1.x... Never reboot your machine with cleaning stopping HDFS, otherwise, yes, it'll corrupt the open files

Comment: but what is the solution for this problem ? how can i over come with this namenode safemode problem and data corrupt??

Comment: `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-dfs.sh`, wait for it, and then turn off your computer?

Comment: still data is lost when i run stop-dfs.sh then restart laptop.. is there any need to add properties in hdfs file? @cricket_007

Comment: No data should be lost when you gracefully stop HDFS using that command. You might have to stop the datanode process as well.

Comment: still when i re start machine then namenode goes permanently in safe mode and data is corrupted.